# glsl compute shader fft implemention done without any memory barriers? how is this not having any race conditions

Tags: graphics, signals, fft

I have been looking over the work of Sergiu Craitoiu on his butterfly fft implementation, however between the 2, 4, 8, and 16 it doesn't seem he is using any memory barriers.  Is there something that I just missed that was implemented before hand to handle race conditions?

http://in2gpu.com/?p=846